# Upgraded from Hibernate 4.3.6 to Hibernate 5.1.0 executing stored procedure with named parameters not working

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, named-parameters

We just upgraded to hibernate 5.1.0.  **The exact same code was working fine in 4.3.6**.  We have some oracle procedure calls following the JPA 2.1 spec utilizing named parameters.  In our case, we had a procedure that had 3 IN parameters and 2 OUT parameters.  All parameters are basic data types(NUMBERS or VARCHAR).

I tried both the JPA 2.1 spec approach and also tried the hibernate specific approach.  Both failed for the same reason.

We get the following error:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters**

I think the error is wrong because.  1) because it's working fine using 4.3.6 and 2) All in parameters are registered and bound.  Out parameters would not be bound but would be registered.

We are using the oracle jdbc driver 11.2.0.2.

Sample Code:

```
    public void testStoredProcedureUsingEntityManagerDirectly() {
        final EntityManager em = anyBean.getEntityManager(); 
        final StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("myschema.my_package.my_proc");
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_paramName1", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_paramName2", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_paramName3", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_outParam1", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_outParam2", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        proc.setParameter("p_paramName1", "some.name@myemail.com");
        proc.setParameter("p_paramName2", "Company Name");
        proc.setParameter("p_paramName3", "ABC12344444");
        proc.execute();
        final Long orgSeqNum = (Long) proc.getOutputParameterValue("o_outParam1");
        final String activeIndicator = (String) proc.getOutputParameterValue("o_outParam2");
        System.out
            .println("Output: o_org_seq_num = '" + orgSeqNum + "', o_org_set_already = '" + activeIndicator + "'");
    }
```

Comment: We hava a similar problem (updated from 4.3.7 to 5.1.0). Error message comes from JDBC driver and says "Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined". We're now using version 5.0.1, which works in our case.